# define measure aggregate at run time

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube

Am using OLAP and i want to make measure functions e.g(count,max,..) to be selected by the user (to be as a filter).

Is there a way to choose measure aggregate function of a cube at run time ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you'll have to use the mdx functions... Avg,Count,Max,Min...

Answer (score 1):

Got a bit more time, I don't think it's possible to switch the aggregation type of a measure in the MDX servers I know. Take into account some improvements (speed and memory) may rely on the kind of aggregation you're using.

Two possible solutions :

- Create calculated members to calculate count,max -> Aggregate(...) issue here is a drop in performance.
- Have already all measures created (amount-max,amount-min) and use a selector or utility dimension to switch it. Utility dimension are not standard dimension as they don't hold values but transformation. You can find a bit of inspiration [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_stats.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot icCube for your help. But am using Pentaho Mondrian  if the utility dimension supported there ?

Comment: You can always create a dimension with a single members and always present in the facts. This was - is - the way in MSAS.